# Splunk adding two values for a timechart

Tags: eval, splunk

I have a SPLUNK search, and want to add the previous values for a third chart.

```
(source="/var/fedex/foo/logs/foo.log" )
    (FOO ) AND 0000 
| timechart  span=1h count as "Value1"
| append  [ 
    search  source="/var/fedex/bar/logs/bar.log"
       (BAR ) AND 0000  
    | timechart  span=1h count as "Value2"
]
| append  [ 
    timechart  span=1h  eval("Value1" + "Value2") as "Value3"
]
```

gives me an error
"Error in 'timechart' command: The eval expression has no fields: 'Value1 + Value2'."

I seem to be running around in circles on this issue.  I am now getting suggestions to go back to my first approach.

```
| append  [ eval("Value1" + "Value2") as "Value3" 
    timechart  span=1h  "Value3"
]
```

see https://answers.splunk.com/answers/168646/timechart-wtih-eval-cant-recognize-fields.html
which gave me a
Error in 'eval' command: The 'eval' function is unsupported or undefined.

Comment: Please share some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Value1=1
Value2=2
Value3=eval(Value1+Value2)=3

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, rather than using `append`. Bring all the data into a single search, then use something like `eventstats` to do a sum (while keeping the existing events).

`(source="/var/fedex/foo/logs/foo.log" (FOO) AND 0000) OR (source="/var/fedex/bar/logs/bar.log" (BAR ) AND 0000) | bucket _time span=1h | stats count by source, _time | | bucket _time span=1h | stats count by source, _time | eventstats sum(count) as Total by source`

Answer (score 0):

### Generate a column calculated from values in other columns

This is actually very straightforward to accomplish using `eval`:

```
|eval Value3=(Value1+Value2)
```

*The above assumes that the timechart table has columns `Value1` and `Value2`.*

---

As described in the documentation for [`eval`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval):

> The eval command creates new fields in your *events* by using existing fields and an arbitrary expression.

This generalizes to also work for *tables* (such as produced by [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart)), as shown:

[image]

---

Here's a complete example based on my answer to [Splunk: How to get two searches in one timechart/graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64742358/splunk-how-to-get-two-searches-in-one-timechart-graph):

```
|makeresults |timechart span=5m count |eval count=0
|appendcols[search (myquery1) |timechart span=5m count as myvar1]
|appendcols[search (myquery2) |timechart span=5m count as myvar2]
|eval mysum=(myvar1+myvar2)
|fields _time, myvar1, myvar2, mysum
```