# Splunk: How to get two searches in one timechart/graph?

Tags: append, splunk

I have to queries which look like this:

```
source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doSomeTasks| timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doSomeTasks" | fillnull

source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doOtherTasks| timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doOtherTasks" | fillnull
```

I now want to get this two searches in one graph (I do not want to sum the numbers I get per search up to one value).

I saw that there is the possibility to take `appendcols` but my trials to use this command were not successful.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doSomeTasks|timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doSomeTasks" appendcols [doOtherTasks| timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doOtherTasks" | fillnull]
```

Comment: In sub-search (inside square brackets) you have to use `search` command explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to PM 77-1 the issue is solved.

This command works:

```
source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doSomeTasks
| timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doSomeTasks" 
| appendcols[search source="/log/ABCD/cABCDXYZ/xyz.log" doOtherTasks | timechart partial=f span=1h count as "#XYZ doOtherTasks" | fillnull]
```

Note: You do not have to mention the source in the second search command if it is the same source as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

### General solution

Generate each data column by using a [subsearch](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/9.0.2208/Search/Aboutsubsearches) query in the following form:

```
|appendcols[search (myquery) |timechart count]
```

---

### Additional steps

The list of one-or-more query columns needs to be preceded by a generated column which establishes the [`timechart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) rows (and gives [`appendcols`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/appendcols) something to append to).

```
|makeresults |timechart count |eval count=0
```

*Note: It isn't strictly required to start with a generated column, but I've found this to be a clean and robust approach. Notably, it avoids problems that may occur in the special-case of "No results found", which otherwise can confuse the visualization rendering. Plus it's more uniform and, as a result, easier to work with.*

Finally, specify each of the [`fields`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fields) to be charted, with `_time` as the x-axis:

```
|fields _time, myvar1, myvar2, myvar3
```

---

### Complete example

```
|makeresults |timechart span=5m count |eval count=0
|appendcols[search (myquery1) |timechart span=5m count as myvar1]
|appendcols[search (myquery2) |timechart span=5m count as myvar2]
|appendcols[search (myquery3) |timechart span=5m count as myvar3]
|fields _time, myvar1, myvar2, myvar3
```

*Be careful to use the same `span` throughout.*

---

### Other hints

When comparing disparate data on the same chart, perhaps to evaluate their relative timing, it's common to have differences in type or scale that can render the overlaid result nearly useless. For cases like this, don't neglect the 'Log' format option for the Y-Axis.

In some cases, it may even be worthwhile to employ data hacks with `eval` to massage the values into a visual comparable state. For example, appending `|eval myvar1=if(myvar1=0,0,1)` deduplicates values when used following `timechart count`. Here's some relevant docs:

- [Mathematical functions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MathematicalFunctions)
- [Comparison and Conditional functions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConditionalFunctions)

Comment: It may be helpful to manage this as a dashboard panel -- particularly to get the benefit of variable substitution for things like `span`.

Comment: Splunk is an amazing tool, but in some ways it is surprisingly limited. Getting charts to do what you want can be a chore, or sometimes seemingly impossible. For example, I am seeing time mismatches in the `_time` value between chart columns (some being incorrect). A similar, very reproducible effect occurs when you try to use timecharts with different `span` values. `appendcols` apparently doesn't guarantee proper row placement. Caveat emptor.

Comment: There are intriguing, but outrageously complicated, workarounds: [here](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Timecharts-and-how-to-avoid-quot-no-results-found-inspect-quot/m-p/535654/highlight/true#M151400) and [here](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/retrieving-timechart-values-when-there-are-no-events/m-p/484865/highlight/true#M135731). For example, the subsearch timechart would be followed by `|append [makeresults |timechart count span=1m |eval count=0] |timechart span=1m sum(count) as myvar`. _Notice that this is based, in part, on the "generated column" logic above._

Comment: Create additional column from math on related columns like `|eval myvar4=(myvar1+myvar2)`.

Comment: Another workaround will be required for a 'Date time range' in the past.

Comment: Something else to look into: [multisearch](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Multisearch) and [union](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Union)